# Distribute VulkanRT with C++ binary

Tags: c++, vulkan

I know there are the official [Vulkan Runtime Libraries](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home) to install on the client PC. Actually, it would be really nice if I could just insert e.g. the needed .dll files in my binary directory so the end user does not have to install an additional dependency. How could I do it?

Comment: Not a programming question, post to SuperUser.

Comment: There are references on the site you linked to the static Vulkan runtime library.

Comment: A Vulkan capable driver already installs the runtime.

Comment: Really? Thanks for these great news! Question answered :)